# Vue.js template do not shows the data

Tags: templates, vue.js

In the [Vue.js Document](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Text):

I test text data binding like bellow:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: "abc"
  }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>


</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
  this will never change:{{* msg }}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue-resource/1.3.4/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But there do not shows the `msg`. why I can not get it?

Answer (score 2):

You document version is `1.x`, and you use the vue.js CDN version is `2.5.13`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
```

The `{{* }}` syntax is removed in Vue `2.x`, you can use `v-once` to replace it:

```
<div id="app" v-once>
  this will never change:{{ msg }}
</div>
```